# Grabbing status updates from facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

This is not a programming-related question.

I am a project manager for a real estate management system that is being written in PHP/Laravel. We are trying to incorporate social aspects for our contact's profiles.

For example, if you know his twitter or instagram accounts, you could easily submit them while creating his account and on his profile page you could easily see what this contact has been up to on twitter or instagram. Sort of like keeping up to date with your client's social lives through social media.

Please understand that this is all done with consent. We wouldn't have his/her twitter account unless he/she had given it up in the first place.

The problem is with Facebook, and since most of our social engagement is through facebook this is starting to become a real issue.

As we know, you cannot grab a user's status unless you are friends with them. So if we added the facebook field in our RMS the same way we did with twitter and instagram, it wouldn't work because we're not friends with that client.

So I thought how about we create a personal account under our company's name, then we send a friend request to the contact. Once he approves, we can go back and edit his account on our RMS to include his facebook username... And I think now we will be able to see his latest facebook statuses.

I think that would work, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Also if there's another way to do it, please enlighten me.

Comment: "This is not a programming-related question." Then why are you asking it on a site dedicated to programming-related questions?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because, as the OP said, 'This is not a programming-related question.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not true that you need to be friends with the specific user. The user needs to give an app of yours permission to access his data. Therefore, Facebook implements the OAuth protocol.

Have a look at the following resources:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.0
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens